# Python, calculating the area inder a gaussian by integration

Tags: python, gaussian

I have a function, a gaussian, I have fitted this to my data from a data file. I now need to integrate the gaussian function to give the area under it.

This is my gaussian function

```
def I(theta,max_x,max_y,sigma):
    return (max_y/(sigma*(math.sqrt(2*pi))))*np.exp(-((theta-max_x)**2)/(2*sigma**2))
```

COMPARING WITH GENERAL FORMULA

> N(x | mu, sigma, n) := (n/(sigma*sqrt(2*pi))) * exp((-(x-mu)^2)/(2*sigma^2))

i.e n = max_y , MU = max_x , x = theta

this is what is given on another page:

> If Phi(z) = integral(N(x|0,1,1), -inf, z); that is, Phi(z) is the integral of the standard normal distribution from >minus infinity up to z, then it's true by the definition of the error function that
>   Phi(z) = 0.5 + 0.5 * erf(z / sqrt(2)).
>
> Likewise, if Phi(z | mu, sigma, n) = integral( N(x|sigma, mu, n),
>   -inf, z); that is, Phi(z | mu, sigma, n) is the integral of the normal distribution given parameters mu, sigma, and n from minus infinity up
>   to z, then it's true by the definition of the error function that
>
> Phi(z | mu, sigma, n) = (n/2) * (1 + erf((x - mu) / (sigma *
>   sqrt(2)))).

I am unsure how this helps?? I just want to integrate my function over the plotted values under the curve. Is it saying this is the integral:

```
Phi(z | mu, sigma, n) = (n/2) * (1 + erf((x - mu) / (sigma * sqrt(2))))
```

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking for. If you want the area under a Gaussian (i.e. the integral over `|R`), this is `Phi(inf)`. Since `erf(inf) = 1)` the result is `(n/2) * sqrt(2) / sigma`, in the one-dimensional case `1 / (sigma sqrt(2))`. To evaluate the indefinite integral you can use the `erf` implementation from the `math` module.

Comment: thanks, still unsure of the correct code to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer you have there is the *indefinite integral*. If you would like a numerical answer between two x limits, you can evaluate that function at two points and take the difference.

Your gaussian function is defined over all real numbers (−∞, +∞) but in practice, you are only interested in the middle part as the tails are *very* close to 0. To obtain a numerical estimate of the total area you can do as you say: evaluate the error function at two points suitably close to 0 on each side of the gaussian's peak and take the difference.

If `Phi(z | mu, sigma, n)` returns a function you could do:

```
integral = Phi(z | mu, sigma, n)
area = integral(X_HIGH) - integral(X_LOW)
```

Comment: could I use the 2 minimums of the curve? i.e. where the curve starts to rise and the point where it comes back down? how would i change the code above to incorporate this? thanks for the reply!

Comment: A Gaussian has no minimum. The area under a Gaussian depends only on `sigma` and your prefactor.

Comment: maybe minimum wasnt the correct term, i mean where its flat, before it rises and where it returns to being flat after it descends. there will be two x values.

Comment: @user3009100 It is never _truly_ flat, it just tends to 0, getting flatter and flatter. Yes, you can use those values. filmor is referring to the fact that there is an exact value to the area of a gaussian, which I don't know off the top of my head!

Comment: thanks again. so please could you give me an example of the code i could use to evaluate the function between the two points.

Comment: thanks Tom, will play around with the code above. total beginner to python so really helped! thanks all!!